# Do you still get a bounce in Google Analytics if all the linked pages/content is loaded dynamically?

Tags: google, google-analytics

Google Analytics describes a bounce as a user that visits and leaves before after their first page.

But if your site is a one page site, with content loaded dynamically using JavaScript, you could have a user on your site go through loads of info, text images; would that still count as a bounce?

Or once they click on an **a-tag** even if it is `<a href="#">` can Google Analytics see that? I'm aware of click tracking in Analytics, but I was wondering does Google pick up these clicks by default?

Answer (score 1):

On such a website, you need to have your javascript trigger Google Analytics "events" when new content is loaded dynamically.  Events can be marked as "interactive" or "non-interactive".  If a user hits an interactive event, analytics counts them as non-bouncing.  If a user hits a non-interactive event, it does not affect whether they bounce or not.

So implementing events correctly drastically improves your bounce rate.  It will also give you lots of insight into what users actually do on your site.  Here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: This is a good answer, and an upvote to you sir! However, the OP should know that GA does not by default consider the click of <a href="#"> as a non-bounce.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to test it? Create a page which only you have access to and see. There can be no better answer as only you know what your code / website does.

Comment: Im not going to down-vote this, but its not really an answer.. more of a comment!

I do agree though - give it a try - let us know